# MSON to JSON-Schema "One of" issue

Tags: json, apiblueprint, mson

I'm try to describe in ApiBlueprint MSON notation an object with variable part.
Here the simple code in ApiBlueprint :

```
 FORMAT: 1A

# Test API

## Services [/Service/{id}]

### GET Service info [GET]


+ Request (application/json)

    + Headers

            Authorization: JWT <token>

+ Response 200 (application/json)

    + Attributes (array[ServiceResource], fixed)



# Data Structures

## Resource (object)
### Properties

+ id: `a6vhAo3FG` (string, fixed)
+ created_at: `2016-07-01T15:11:09.553Z` (string, required)
+ updated_at: `2017-11-22T08:07:55.002Z` (string, required)


## Service (object)

### Properties
+ type: tcp_service (string, required)
- One Of
    - config (TcpService, required)
    - config (IcmpService, required)


## ServiceResource (Resource)
### Properties

- Include Service

## TcpService (object)

### Properties

+ port: `80` (number, required) 
+ request_str: `HEAD` (string, required)
+ expect_response_str: `200 OK` (string, required)

## IcmpService (object)

### Properties

+ timeout_ms: `1000` (number, required)
+ packet_size_bytes: `1000` (number, required)
+ ttl: `128` (number, required)
```

It renders perfectly in apiary.io but validation of generated Json Schema in https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com reports an error:

```
[ {
  "level" : "error",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "#",
    "pointer" : "/items"
  },
  "instance" : {
    "pointer" : "/0"
  },
  "domain" : "validation",
  "keyword" : "additionalProperties",
  "message" : "object instance has properties which are not allowed by the schema: [\"config\"]",
  "unwanted" : [ "config" ]
} ]
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

**Is there any way to discribe in MSON the array of objects where the object has a variant part which gives correct JSON Schema?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`fixed-type` type attribute](https://apiblueprint.org/documentation/mson/specification.html#353-type-attribute). `fixed` would mean that the values are fixed and cannot be anything other than the provided example value. When you used `fixed-type` you are indicating that the type is fixed, but the values are not.

```
+ Attributes (array[ServiceResource], fixed-type)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinkin that it was in the Draft MSON spec only and didn't notice 'fixed-type' in spec.

Comment: You've made my day!